# How do I asynchronously access my Java back end service from Rails app thorugh Apache Thrift?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, asynchronous, thrift

So I have a pretty heavy back end service written in Java that is connected to a Rails app through Apache Thrift. I am using TCP connection to access the back end service which is running on a remote machine.

For each incoming request, my Rails Controller does the following:

```
transport = Thrift::BufferedTransport.new(Thrift::Socket.new(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
protocol = Thrift::BinaryProtocol.new(transport)
client = MyService::Client.new(protocol)
transport.open()

@result = client.processUserRequest(query)

transport.close()
```

Now the above service call clearly blocks for the entire time the back end server processes the request. Is there a way I can make this asynchronous? So that while a request is being serviced by the back end server the Web Front End can continue to accept incoming HTTP requests. What are my options to accomplish this?

I am using Phusion Passenger with Apache. I expect to see few dozens to few hundred concurrent connections at most. My Web server is on a small ec2 instance with 1.7 GB RAM.

I am quite new to Ruby/Rails (coming from a Java/C++ background), so still trying to grasp how things work in the Ruby land.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply use the `async` modifier in the Thrift definition. The method return type has to be void. Note that you will not get guarantee that the message was processed successfully, just that it was sent over to the Server.

```
service MyService
{
   async void processUserRequest(1: Query query);
}
```

Comment: I know I can use the  async versions of the Thrift service, but how do I capture the return values? Callback? Events?